# android Store User name and password in database and use it for multiple activities

Tags: android, database, sqlite, authentication

I want to Store Username and password in Global variable or in database

actually I have a one time activity..I tried with shared preferences...

so I have given this for that..

```
public class Login extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPrefs";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    if (settings.getString("logged", "").toString().equals("logged")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
            EditText passsword= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            Snipper usertype= (Snipper) findViewById(R.id.ut);
            Snipper ctype= (Snipper) findViewById(R.id.ct);

            if(username.getText().toString().length() > 0 && password.getText().toString().length() > 0 && usertype.getSelectedItem().toString().length()>0 && ctype.getSelectedItem().toString().length()>0) {
                //if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {

                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("logged", "logged");
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                //}
            }
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Here along with User name and pass word I am saving total 4 values...

So I want to Save them as Database or Global variables and Use them In **Multiple Activities**...

Can any one tell with Example or correct my code... Please don't post books or guide lines tell me example link or code... where I need to change..

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Global variables won't hold their values after the application is terminated. You'll have to use either SharedPrefs or Database to persist those values. And then when your app launches you can populate your global variables.

Comment: In my current approach I want to use this for multiple activities,here with intent I am using only one activities.,.. can any one tell me with example in Database... thanks @camelCaseCoder I forgot that Global variables wont hold after terminate...

Comment: Please have a look at this comprehensive tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: thanks @camelCaseCoder sir,,, can you post your answer like a example... here  I want to store user Id,pw,xyz,abc as 4 user inputs in database... and use them in multiple activities,,, like user id,pw is common for all and xyz for some classes and abc for some classes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing "logged in" key which is helping you check user is logged in or not. And it is persisted in the application.

You can do the same thing to store username and password by storing HashMap in sharedPref.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("username", username);
map.put("password", password);

SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("TEST", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
  editor.putString(key, map.get(key));
}

editor.apply();
```

Get value from sharedPref

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("TEST", 0);
 HashMap<String, String> map= (HashMap<String, String>) prefs.getAll(); //Get all list of saved username and password 

 for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        String value=map.get(key);
 }
```

Your activity :

```
public class Login extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPrefs";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

    HashMap<String, String> map= (HashMap<String, String>) settings.getAll();

    if(map != null && ( map.containsKey("username") &&  map.containsKey("password")
        map.get("username") != null && map.get("password") != null){
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /*if (settings.getString("logged", "").toString().equals("logged")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }*/

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
            EditText passsword= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            Snipper usertype= (Snipper) findViewById(R.id.ut);
            Snipper ctype= (Snipper) findViewById(R.id.ct);

            if(username.getText().toString().length() > 0 && password.getText().toString().length() > 0 && usertype.getSelectedItem().toString().length()>0 && ctype.getSelectedItem().toString().length()>0) {
                //if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {

                    /*SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("logged", "logged");
                    editor.commit();*/

                    String uname = username.getText().toString();
                    String pass  = password.getText().toString();

                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("username", uname);
                    map.put("password", pass);

                    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
                        editor.putString(key, map.get(key));
                    }

                    editor.apply();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                //}
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Please read [SharedPreference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) tutorial.In this activity how i mention the SharedPreference get use same way you can call it using LoginPrefs key.

Hope it will work for you.

Cheers...!!!

Comment: Hi, @Don'tBenegative after storing into sharedPref, you can get those values in multiple activities if you needed.

Comment: Can you tell me How to use this in My activity I am unable to use it.. Please update your answer with my code.. and also for using them in another activity... I am confused... Please update I will mark & upvote you... please see my update question..

Comment: Thanks @CA2802  But I am getting this error at user name and password..`Wrong 2nd Argument type Found:'android.widget.EditText'   required: 'java.lang.String'`

Comment: @Don'tBenegative sorry username.getText().toString() need to be present over there coz I directly add there as a string you need to get the string and add it. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you Yesterday  I used `getText().toString();` and `getSelectedItem().toString();` worked .... fine... thanks a lot ... please upvote my question.. some mot--f_ck-r person down voted..

Comment: Here some time I am getting both user name and password in Key... can you tell me what is key... I changed key to username... or pw but I am getting error,,, Please help me I will Upvote some of your Answers... from your profile...

Answer (score -1):

Your current approach is correct, but you have wrong understand of `SharedPreferences`.

> In my current approach I want to use this for multiple activities

You can read and write the data using`SharedPreferences` from different activities.

Comment: You already know how to write and read `SharedPreference` data, just do the same on other activities