# How use shared Prefs value to start a specific activity

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34736966/5010291) to store data in shared preferences

Here I am taking input from a Spinner

```
Spinner ftype = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s1);
Spinner vtype = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s2);

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Sri_eta_SP, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

map.put("ftype",ft);
map.put("vtype",vt);

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
editor.putString(key, map.get(key));
}
```

Over there I saved a saved a data like this

```
<?xml version="1.,0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
<map>
<string name="ftype">Android</string>
<string name="vtype">phone</string>
</map>
```

here spinner s1 contains list of values like Android,IOS,Windows
here spinner s2 contains list of values like phone,tab

So here I want to use specific value..like android or 2016 from any spinner

I am using like this

```
if((map.containsKey("ftype") && map.get("ftype")!= null) && map.get("ftype")==Android){
MainActivity.this.finish();
Intent c = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Android.class);
c.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(c);
finish();
}
else{
    MainActivity.this.finish();
    Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Select.class);
    a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(a);
    finish();
}
```

But its not working Its going with `else` condition
I tried with this also

```
if(map.get("ftype")==Android){
```

and this

```
for (String ftype : map.keySet()) {
     Android = map.get(ftype);
       
     if(map.get("ftype")==Android){

   }
```

But its not working... can any one suggest me if value contains specific one then it should start a activity....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But its not working Its going with else condition...

Because of comparing String values using `==`, use `String.equals` instead of `==`.like:

```
if(map.get("ftype").equals("Android"){
  // your code here
}
```